# Passage from “Les Gommes” containing “porte en grand”

Tags: sens, expressions

I'm reading *Les Gommes* and I was wondering about the meaning of this sentence:

> *Et s'il rallume avant d'ouvrir la porte en grand ?*

They are speaking here of someone who has been shot. Are they just asking what if he woke up, or is "porte en grand" slang for dying?

> *Garinati aurait bien pu éteindre tant qu'il aurait voulu, si l'autre en arrivant avait rallumé avant de pousser le battant à fond, ça revenait bien au même.*

That passage I just can't get.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is :

> And what about if he turns on the light before opening the door wide?

As the person is either dead or gone, it is a narrative present, an hypothesis about what might have happened.